# Ranking duplicates in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table with three columns `Id`, `A` and `B`. `Id` is unique, but I want to identify and rank duplicates across Columns `A` and `B`.

So for the following data

```
 Id | A | B
----|---|---
  1 | a | b
  2 | a | c
  3 | a | b
  4 | c | b
  5 | a | c
```

I want to get the following 'ranks' for each `Id`

```
 Id | Rank
----|------
  1 |    1
  2 |    1
  3 |    2
  4 |    1
  5 |    2
```

I though I could achieve this using an LOD but trying this doesn't work. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

I basically want the row with the lowest Id for a fixed `A` and `B` to have a rank of 1; the next lowest Id for the same fixed `A` and `B` to have a rank of 2 etc.

The following was what I attempted but it's not working - I need to run an aggregate on `Id` for the `RANK` function to work but I can't think which to use.

```
{
    FIXED [A], [B] :
    RANK([Id])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your calculation.

1. RANK is a table calculation and Table calculations are not allowed to be used in LODs
2. A Table calculation only accepts an aggregation or a constant, not just a field name

This kind of scenarios can be easily handled with Table calculations  RANK or INDEX. For example, create a calculated field INDEX with formula `INDEX()` and build the view as below.(Please note that INDEX is calculated using 'Pane Down')

[image]